# How to make a function synchronous in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I made this function that retrieve the flight data from Aviationstack API(a flight API ). I'm new to nodejs and I want to make this function synchronous using 'sync-request' so that when I call anywhere I could get something in return. here is the function code :

```
    function get_flights_by_date(date) { 
      
      let url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&flight_status=scheduled'
     
      request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error:', error);
        } else {
          let vol = JSON.parse(body)
          num = vol.pagination.limit
          for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            dep = vol.data[i].departure.airport
            depart = vol.data[i].departure.timezone
            arrival = vol.data[i].arrival.timezone
            arr = vol.data[i].arrival.airport
            flight_date = vol.data[i].flight_date
            number = vol.data[i].flight.number
             console.log('flight number:' + ' ' + number + ' ' + 'from' + ' ' + depart + ' ' + 'at' + ' ' + dep + ' ' + 'airport' + ' ' + 'to' + ' ' + arrival + ' ' + 'at' + ' ' + arr + ' ' + 'airport' + ' ' + 'on' + ' ' + flight_date + '.')
            
          }
        }

  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a way to make a sync code in node js

There are few approach to make any code sync

1. callback

   What you are doing, this will fail when you will call directly from other function. instead you can do this

   ```
    function get_flights_by_date(date, callback) { 

     let url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&flight_status=scheduled'

     request(url, function (err, response, body) {
       if (err) {
         console.log('error:', error);
         callback(err);
       } else {
         let vol = JSON.parse(body)
         num = vol.pagination.limit
         for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
           dep = vol.data[i].departure.airport
           depart = vol.data[i].departure.timezone
           arrival = vol.data[i].arrival.timezone
           arr = vol.data[i].arrival.airport
           flight_date = vol.data[i].flight_date
           number = vol.data[i].flight.number
            console.log('flight number:' + ' ' + number + ' ' + 'from' + ' ' + depart + ' ' + 'at' + ' ' + dep + ' ' + 'airport' + ' ' + 'to' + ' ' + arrival + ' ' + 'at' + ' ' + arr + ' ' + 'airport' + ' ' + 'on' + ' ' + flight_date + '.')

         }
         callback(null, number)
       }
    });}
    function mainFunction(){
       var date = '';
       get_flights_by_date(date, function(err, result){
           if(err){
               return err
           }
           return result
       })
   }
   ```
2. promise

   ```
   function get_flights_by_date(date) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   let url =
     "http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&flight_status=scheduled";

   request(url, function (err, response, body) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("error:", error);
       reject(err);
     } else {
       let vol = JSON.parse(body);
       num = vol.pagination.limit;
       for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         dep = vol.data[i].departure.airport;
         depart = vol.data[i].departure.timezone;
         arrival = vol.data[i].arrival.timezone;
         arr = vol.data[i].arrival.airport;
         flight_date = vol.data[i].flight_date;
         number = vol.data[i].flight.number;
       }
       resolve(number);
     }
   });});
   }
   async function main() {
     try {
       await get_flights_by_date("");
     } catch (error) {}
   }
   ```
3. Async lib

or you can use this lib to do your entire code here https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/understanding-node-js-async-flows-parallel-serial-waterfall-and-queues-6f9c4badbc17

**I would recommend you to go for async lib as it is easy to scale in this fashion**

Answer (score 0):

I would totally avoid using synchronous code when ever possible, as this does not scale. This is a very bad practice, and will halt your server as long as the request is still fetching...

You can (And should) use `async`/`await`, or `Promise` to wait for the data while making sure your server is available.

If you want to avoid the `then` callback on `Promise`, just use `async`/`await`

Converted to use `Promise` and `async`/`await`:

```
function get_flights_by_date(date) { 
  const url = 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&flight_status=scheduled'
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {        
        const data = JSON.parse(body); // Process your data
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  })
}

function promiseExample() {
  get_flights_by_date(new Date()).then(resultData => console.log(resultData))
}

async function example() {
  const resultData = await get_flights_by_date(new Date());
  console.log(resultData);
}
```